# How to configure eslint-plugin-import so the imports are sorted alphabetically without taking into consideration the file path?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I can not find the documentation for configuring the "eslint-plugin-import" rules.

I would like to sort my imports alphabetically by class/interface/etc.. name without taking into consideration the file path.

For example, with my current configuration, here is how my imports are sorted by ESLint:

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu'; <---------------- Look at this line
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

import logo from './logo.svg';
```

Here is the configuration I use

```
"import/order": [
  "error",
  {
    "groups": [
      "builtin",
      "external",
      "internal"
    ],
    "pathGroups": [
      {
        "pattern": "react",
        "group": "external",
        "position": "before"
      }
    ],
    "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": [
      "react"
    ],
    "newlines-between": "always",
    "alphabetize": {
      "order": "asc",
      "caseInsensitive": true
    }
  }
],
```

I would like to sort them this way:

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu'; <---------------- Look at this line
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

import logo from './logo.svg';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and I also wanted to sort as you are mentioning in your question. However, currently it seems it is not possible.

I have solved it for me with slightly different approach. I am treating `@mui/material/` as one path group and `@mui/icons-material` as another.

With below config

```
"import/order": [
        "error",
        {
            "groups": ["builtin", "external", "internal"],
            "pathGroups": [
                {
                    "pattern": "react",
                    "group": "external",
                    "position": "before"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "@mui/icons-material/**",
                    "group": "external",
                    "position": "after"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "@mui/material/**",
                    "group": "external",
                    "position": "before"
                }
            ],
            "pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes": ["react"],
            "newlines-between": "always",
            "alphabetize": {
                "order": "asc",
                "caseInsensitive": true
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

You will have a result like this

```
import "./App.css";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

import MenuIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Menu";

import logo from "./logo.svg";
```

Notice the separation (new line) between `@mui/icons-material/` and `@mui/material/`

This is achieved with the settings in `pathGroups`. You can add these kind of pattern for any other import which maybe coming from `@mui` or any other source.

I understand that this may not be the exact solution but it maybe the most suitable at this point. at least for me it is :).